# solution for copy values between two table without type all of structure

Tags: php, mysql

i use this code

```
update 
contracts a, 
contracts_history b 
set 
a.name_surname=b.name_surname
```

My table has 64 columns and I am looking for a solution to copy all data with out having to specify column names - along these lines:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `contracts_history` 
         SELECT * FROM `contracts` WHERE id='$contract_id'";
```

Comment: Your question is really unclear - why would the update work when you specify no criteria to match records. And what do you mean by `64 structures`

Comment: @adrian: probably means 64 fields. which would be a bit tedious to list, but that usually just means OP is lazy

Comment: @MarcB Never! OP's always provide all the information we need to answer their questions ;-)

Comment: @MarcB Yeah, it does - it is a followup from the last question he posted an hour ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `insert into select...` syntax as long as your tables are exactly the same number of fields with matching datatypes - otherwise you will *have* to use column names to specify what you want to copy.

I just ran the following as an example for you to show you the syntax:

```
mysql> use test
Database changed
mysql> show tables;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> create table test1 (id int(2), varry varchar(3));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> create table test2 (id int(2), barry varchar(3));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> insert into test2 values(1,'aaa');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test1;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into test1 (select * from test2);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from test1;
+------+-------+
| id   | varry |
+------+-------+
|    1 | aaa   |
+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> alter table test2 add column third int(1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> update test2 set barry='ccc';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> insert into test1 (select * from test2);
ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
mysql>
```